# iMacros, selecting one link from a table

Tags: select, row, regression, imacros

I need to make an iMacros script that selects a link with a common caption, based on a value that precedes it in a table. For example, I have a webpage with rows of data that looks like this:

APPLE     Click Me

BANANA    Click Me

PEAR      Click Me

GRAPES    Click Me

ORANGE    Click Me

The "fruit name" is not a hyperlink, but the "Click Me" is.  I want to have my script always click on the link beside "PEAR".

I cannot just use TAG POS=3 because the table is different every time, and PEAR is not always in position 3.

So I need some sort of script that finds the value I specify ("PEAR" in this case), then uses TAG POS=x.

How can I do that?  (prefer to use JS please as I am using the FireFox plugin)

Comment: Use search and search javascript scripting imacros. There is a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to use relative tags.  You could setup an anchor tag for pear, then use relative tags to click the hyperlink.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:PEAR
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*
```

Find the SPAN with the name PEAR, then click the next link tag with any text.

Relative tags begin searching for matching HTML tags from the last successful tag.  They begin with R and are then followed by the offset value.

Wiki Link:  http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG_parameters_explained#Relative_positioning explains Relative Tags.

Answer (score 0):

My table was exactly the same, here is what worked for me:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:PEAR
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=txt:*
```